# Customize the pagination template in category page - Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, category, javascript

I'm trying to change how the page selector works on category pages for this:

[image: Pages]

To:  "Page 1 of 6"

But I cant seem to find the file the code sits in to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer this [link](http://gworks.mobi/blog/2016/06/16/magento-2-next-previous-link/) to understand about how to add pagination (it helps to understand the concept).

If you are looking to customize, take a look the below block and temaplates

**Block**

```
<magento-root>/app/code/Magento/Theme/Block/Html/Pager.php

                         or

<magento-root>/vendor/magento/module_theme/Block/Html/Pager.php
```

**Template:**

```
<magento-root>/app/code/Magento/Theme/view/frontend/templates/html/pager.phtml

                        or

<magento-root>/vendor/magento/module_theme/view/frontend/templates/html/pager.phtml
```

you can find the declaration of block in layout here
`<magento-root>app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

```
<block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
```

Comment: Is this for Magento 1.x?

Comment: no @Mark this is magento 2.x :-) .updated my question please check

Comment: Thank you that makes more sense to me now. I'll take a look thanks :)

Comment: hi @Bilal, need help in the same issue...im trying to override the pagination from my custom theme...but im not able to get ... http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/133188/issue-in-overriding-core-phtml-files-in-custom-theme-magento2