# Problem overrding .phtml file: Magento 2 Catalog module

Tags: magento2

**Problem :** Trying to override the default Magento phtml file, im getting error

**I need to get these:**  (Pagination in footer,  Sorter)

[image]

My custom Modules:

```
1) Vendor/TglsSearch  --> Override from Magento CatalogSearch
2) Vendor/Tglcatalog ---> from Magento Catalo
```

In **app\design\frontend\Vendor\tag**

[image]

**UPDATED CODE:**

**REMOVED the below folder**

In **Magento_Catalog folder** :

```
templates\product\list\toolbar.phtml
templates\product\list\toolbar\amount.phtml
templates\product\list\toolbar\limiter.phtml
templates\product\list\toolbar\sorter.phtml
templates\product\list\toolbar\viewmode.phtml
```

This is what i get blank page without results in front page:

[image]

Added the mentioned code in Block file:

**Vendor\Module\Block\Product\ListProduct.php**

```
class ListProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
    public function __construct(
    /*passing all Constructors parameters to the parent class */
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
     CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,

    \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $tglssearchHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $catalogResourceModelProductCollectionFactory,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $catalogConfig,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,      //Pagination
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->tglssearchHelper = $tglssearchHelper;
    $this->catalogResourceModelProductCollectionFactory = $catalogResourceModelProductCollectionFactory;
    $this->catalogConfig = $catalogConfig;
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;

    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;  //Pagination
    $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;

      parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $postDataHelper,
        $layerResolver,
        $categoryRepository,
        $urlHelper,
        $data
    );
    //updated code
     $collection= $this->_getProductCollection();
    $this->setCollection($collection);

}

public function _prepareLayout(){
   parent::_prepareLayout();
    if ($this->_getProductCollection()) { 

        // create pager block for collection 

        $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();  

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                        'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager', 'list.pager'
                )->setCollection(
                $this->_getProductCollection() // assign collection to pager
        );  
        $toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager); // set pager block in layout
        // called prepare sortable parameters
        $collection = $this->_getProductCollection();  

        // use sortable parameters
        $orders = $this->getAvailableOrders();  

        if ($orders) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        $sort = $this->getSortBy();
        if ($sort) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        $dir = $this->getDefaultDirection();
        if ($dir) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        $modes = $this->getModes();
        if ($modes) {
            $toolbar->setModes($modes);
        }
        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        $this->_getProductCollection()->load();
   }
    return $this;
}

protected function _getProductCollection()
{
      $tagalys = $this->tglssearchHelper->getSearchData();

        if($tagalys == false) {
            return parent::_getProductCollection();
        } else {

        $searchResult = $tagalys;

        if(empty($searchResult)) {
            return parent::_getProductCollection();
        }

        $collection = $this->_productCollection = $this->catalogResourceModelProductCollectionFactory->create()
             ->addAttributeToSelect($this->catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
             ->setStore($this->storeManager->getStore())
             ->addFieldToFilter('visibility', \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH)
             ->addAttributeToFilter( 'entity_id', array( 'in' => $searchResult['results'] ) );

        $orderString = array('CASE e.entity_id');
        foreach($searchResult['results'] as $i => $productId) {
            $orderString[] = 'WHEN '.$productId.' THEN '.$i;
        }
        $orderString[] = 'END';
        $orderString = implode(' ', $orderString);

    $collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr($orderString));

        return $this->_productCollection;

    }
}


public function getToolbarBlock()
{
    $blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName();
    if ($blockName) {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName);
        if ($block) {
            return $block;
        }
    }
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, uniqid(microtime()));
    return $block;
}

public function getMode()                       //Pagination
{
    return $this->getChildBlock('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
}

public function getToolbarHtml()        //Pagination
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
}

protected function getPriceRender()
{
    return $this->getLayout()->getBlock('product.price.render.default');
}

protected function _getConfig()
{
    return $this->_catalogConfig;
}
}
```

**For phtml**:

**\app\design\frontend\Vendor\tag\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml**

```
<?php
   $_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
   $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
 <?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<div class="message info empty"><div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
 <?php else: ?>
   <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>        //Have called here
     ....
     ....
    <?php echo($iterator == count($_productCollection)+1) ? '</li>' : '' ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>    //Have called here
    ....
```

This is what i get if i click on Category link in frontend.

[image]

**In Magento_CatalogSearch** :

```
templates\result.phtml
```

**In Magento_Theme** :

```
templates\html\pager.phtml
layout\default.html
web\images\my_logo.png
```

**NOW the result.phtml error seems to be gone, but still my products are not rendering in frontend with pagination**

In

```
Admin->Content->Design configuration-> Enabled my Custom Theme.
```

**NOTE:** **In my custom module, i have removed the view folder which had templates and layout files.**

**Problem**:

I  have to get the pager(pagination), Sorter etc from the above phtml files.

1) But my products are not rendered from result.phtml (But my var/log has product ids)... frontend not displaying

2) No pagination or sorter appearing

Comment: refer this answer to solve your 1st and 3rd problem http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/86190/36463 . In this answer link follow "Mage2.PRO" answer. kandy ans not work for me

Comment: From the above link, should i have to give as mentioned by Mage2.pro in the app/desin/<overidden template file> ?if so i tried the same, but Pagination is not appearing(i have kept pager phtml and toolbar.phtml) and catalog page is coming like as shown in the screenshot above...Pls suggest

Answer (score 5):

It seems you have to set pager and sorting in your custom phtml file.

I have followed below steps pr add pagination and sorting.

In your block file add below code for add pagination:

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
    $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
    parent::__construct($context, $data);

    // Get your custom collection here

    $collection = $this->getCustomCollection();

    $this->setCollection($collection);
}

public function _prepareLayout()
{

    parent::_prepareLayout();
    if ($this->getCollection()) {

        // create pager block for collection 

        $toolbar = $this->getToolbarBlock();

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager', 'list.pager'
        )->setCollection(
            $this->getCollection() // assign collection to pager
        );
        $toolbar->setChild('product_list_toolbar_pager', $pager); // set pager block in layout
        // called prepare sortable parameters
        $collection = $this->getCollection();

        // use sortable parameters
        $orders = $this->getAvailableOrders();

        if ($orders) {
            $toolbar->setAvailableOrders($orders);
        }
        $sort = $this->getSortBy();
        if ($sort) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultOrder($sort);
        }
        $dir = $this->getDefaultDirection();
        if ($dir) {
            $toolbar->setDefaultDirection($dir);
        }
        $modes = $this->getModes();
        if ($modes) {
            $toolbar->setModes($modes);
        }
        $toolbar->setCollection($collection);

        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
    }

    return $this;
}

public function getToolbarHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
}

public function getToolbarBlock()
{
    $blockName = $this->getToolbarBlockName();
    if ($blockName) {
        $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($blockName);
        if ($block) {
            return $block;
        }
    }
    $block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($this->_defaultToolbarBlock, uniqid(microtime()));

    return $block;
}

public function getMode()
{
    return $this->getChildBlock('toolbar')->getCurrentMode();
}
```

Also define below property:

```
protected $_defaultToolbarBlock = 'Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar';
```

In phtml file add below code before and after listing:

```
<?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
```

Comment: The phtml files are same as in core pasted in the above mentioned folder! and i have added the protected $_defaultToolbarBlock= 'Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar'; in my custom ListProduct.php

Comment: All my custom phtml files seems to be called, but y not my categories and product collection in search not loading!

Comment: for pagination you don't need to overwrite any phtml file. and also it seems you have not set collection in your construct. and i am not sure but try your toolbar code in _prepareLayout function instead of _beforeToHtml

Comment: Can u please give me an example code to get the pagination (without overriding phtml) in my block file? i mean i need what are the exact functions that i have to keep, im confused!

Comment: I commented out -beforeToHtml() and added the getToolbarBlock() in prepareLayout() an also set the collection in construct(), i get main.CRITICAL: Illegal state [] []
in system.log

Comment: If i remove the overriden templates from my theme, then too the Magentos core theme calls, but again the products dont load

Comment: As I mentioned in answer, you have to only set collection and add toolbar block in layout and echo toolbar html in phtml file

Comment: ok whats the folder path for my layout...should tat be inside app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/layout/ or app/code/Vedr/module/view...Please share the code for layout under <body>

Comment: sorry, layout means in _prepareLayout function set toolbar and pager block as I mentioned in may answer

Comment: Please find the updated code, i have included in the layout() and called in the phtml...and still y am i facing the same issue...cleared all cach

Comment: Any suggestions on this @Jaimin? i followed as u said in the above updated code!!

Comment: it seems you are getting some error, can you please enbale developer mode and provide proper error, so I can assist you

Comment: I get i get main.CRITICAL: Illegal state [] [] in system.log, there is not exception log also

Comment: enable developer mode using bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer and add below lines in index.php file. error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); you can show exect error.

Comment: Devmode is already enabled...Enabled display_errors in app/bootstrap.php and the only line i get in system.log is [2016-08-31 06:44:36] main.CRITICAL: Illegal state [] [] under Category page

Comment: by adding in index.php you can see error in browser not in log. Also may be error is related to your custom collection. Please check with normal collection once.